# Download hourly relative humidity using GLDAS using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api, google-earth-engine-explorer

Does anyone know how I can download hourly GLDAS relative humidity (%) using Google Earth Engine? The only output that I am able to get is specific humidity at a specific location, and am having trouble converting this. Is there a way of just obtaining RH straight from GLDAS?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand [this](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2360/how-do-i-convert-specific-humidity-to-relative-humidity/2361#2361) post correctly, it could be approximated like this:

```
var image = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V20/NOAH/G025/T3H').first()

// https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/2361
var relativeHumidity = image.expression(
  '0.263 * p * q * (exp(17.67 * (T - T0) / (T - 29.65))) ** -1', {
    T: image.select('Tair_f_inst'),
    T0: 273.16,
    p: image.select('Psurf_f_inst'),
    q: image.select('Qair_f_inst')
  }
).float()

Map.addLayer(relativeHumidity, {min: 0, max: 100}, 'relativeHumidity')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/cdc1f107bfc53595b6ac7d3ce2b09a55

It get some values > 100, but maybe that's error from the approximation? At least this could give you a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

How can I add a date to this script? This is the link:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d38ed751f6d273a5e89123ec0a6e8427

I have an error stated as Line 9: image.expression is not a function.

Comment: Hi there.  You should post a new question rather than asking in an answer.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/258738)

Comment: Thank you I post new question yesterday